# Plotting points in a pixel grid on Julia

Tags: plot, graphics, julia, pixel, line-plot

I am using this algorithm to check if it gives sequential pixel-points while plotting a line between the points (1,1) and (4,13):

```
using Plots
function plotline(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    a=(x2-x1)/(y2-y1)
    c=(x2*y1-x1*y2)/(y2-y1)
    y=collect(y1:y2)
    x=y.*a
    x=round.(x.-c)
    display(plot(x,y,label="plotline",shape=:circle, color=:red,))
    #println(x)

end

plotline(1,1,4,13)
```

The plot command gives me a continous line which is not really helpful. I am wondering if there is a way to plot the points somewhat like this:
[Grid Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TIuB.png)

My first idea was if I could somehow turn it into a kind of heatmap but I am not really used to them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use heatmap to visualize -- how about this? Haven't fully checked all edge cases (i.e. this assumes x2>x1 and y2>y1) but it should be a good starting point...fun problem! Seems like the kind of thing computer graphics do under the hood all the time to figure out which pixels to light up.

```
using Plots
x1 = 1; y1 = 1; x2 = 4; y2 = 13; pixSize=1
function genPixelLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,pixSize=1)
    m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1); b = y2-m*x2 #slope and intercept of line
    xline = x1:x2; line = m.*xline.+b #line itself
    xpix = x1:pixSize:x2; ypix = y1:pixSize:y2 #pixel centers
    pixels = zeros(length(xpix),length(ypix)) #initialize pixel grid
    xMins = xpix.-(pixSize/2); xMaxs = xpix.+(pixSize/2) #bounding edges in x
    for (yBin,yp) in enumerate(ypix) #go through bounding horizontal lines
        yMin = yp-pixSize/2; yMax = yp+pixSize/2 #top and bottom bounds
        xMin = (yMin-b)/m; xMax = (yMax-b)/m #x values at top and bottom bounds
        xBins = (xMax.>xMins) .&& (xMin.<=xMaxs) #we want the maximum x to greater than the minimum bounding line in x and vice versa
        pixels[xBins,yBin] .= 1.0 #light pixel up where conditions are satisfied
    end
    return (xpix,ypix,pixels),(xline,line)
end
        
pix,l = genPixelLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,pixSize)
heatmap(pix[1],pix[2],pix[3]',colorbar=false) #note have to plot transpose because of how heatmap works internally, pix[1] and pix[2] are the 1D x and y arrays of pixel centers
plot!(l[1],l[2],lw=2,label="line")
vline!([pix[1].-pixSize/2,pix[1].+pixSize/2],label="",c=:purple) #visualize the bounding boxes the function calculated to determine which cells to light up
hline!([pix[2].-pixSize/2,pix[2].+pixSize/2],c=:purple,label="pixel edges")
plot!(widen=false,tickdirection=:out,aspect_ratio=:equal,
    xlims=(x1-pixSize/2,x2+pixSize/2),ylims=(y1-pixSize/2,y2+pixSize/2),
    legend=:outerright,xlabel="x",ylabel="y",size=(600,800))
```

Outputs the following plot:
[image: pixelated line]

Comment: Thank you for your approach! Indeed this is the case a computer finds out what pixel it should light if the slope is greater than 1. It seems though that it gets too complicated and far more different than the one from my textbook. I am not sure how you used the yBins and xBins but I will try to mess around and find out. If I understood right the heat map command with the false colorbar needs a 3rd vector to decide what should light up from the other two vectors (?)

Comment: Also on your last lines you are adding a "!" after every command. Is this a way to add details and keep plotting on the grid that was created by the heatmap? Sorry but I am new to using code in order to plot anything

Comment: yes, in Julia functions that end with ! usually "mutate" existing objects. So the first Plotting call (`heatmap()`) doesn't get a !, but every call after that does because we are modifying the same plot. Tried to leave comments about what the `yBins` and `xBins` are doing -- if you look at the purple grid basically we use those to figure out which "bin" you need to light up. I set it up to loop through every yBin (each row essentially) and check which (if any) xBins in that row need to light up based on the conditional statement.

Comment: And yes, heatmap takes three arguments (you can read more in Julia documentation) where the first 2 are 1D arrays corresponding to the x and y values of the third argument which is a 2D array which encodes the colors of each grid cell (which are set in the for loop in my function above). 

Also there are surely many ways to solve this problem, this is just the first way I thought of when I saw your question and I have no computer graphics experience so I'm sure there are better ways. :)